Aggregating Image Stream (Video) to Audio in Real-Time
For the simplicity, aggregation technique is just averaging (pooling) entire grayscaled image pixel into one amplitude.
So, in other word the camera is acting as light sensor, where more white pixel means more light intensity.
Now, for every amplitude that has been aggregated, I want make amplitude value represented as frequency of sine wave to be played as audio.
The problem is, we can't just assume the sample rate is 44100, I think the sample rate is depending on FPS.
Moreover I need to consider Nyquist's Theorem where sample rate must be greater than the maximum frequency of signal.
So, if I want 440 Hz to be played, I need to wait at least 880 frame to be buffered.
If the FPS is 30, then I need at least wait 29 seconds. But, for the duration of sound to be played, I don't know.
I implemented it in OpenCV by ChatGPT, but it worse, I heard discrete sound (it's like play audio and stop audio repeteadly, there is gap between it), because ChatGPT assumed the sample rate 44100.
Overall, I expect this:
Given incoming image continously (video), it converts the overall light into continously sine wave sound where the frequency depends on light.
In another word, more light means more higher frequency.
How do I play the sound of sine wave where its frequency depends on light continously without gap?
I accept the latency trade-off due to processing.

I think you best bet is to run an oscillator continuously at 44.1 kHz sampling rate and just update it's frequency every time a new frame has been processed. Its probably best to do this in two separate threads.
Human perception of both light intensity and pitch follow a logarithmic sensitivity curve, so you will probably have to play around with the way how light maps to frequency. You want to map the dynamic range of your video to the intended audio frequency range.
Even if you get this all running, its unlikely to sound "good". Listening to pure sine waves can be quite annoying.

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import time
from collections import deque
from itertools import repeat, starmap

# Set the sample rate of the audio (in samples per second).
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100

# Number of frames per buffer to control audio data transfer frequency.
FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 2048

# Set maximum buffer size to hold up to 2 seconds of audio data, lower buffer size means lower latency but prone to underflow.
MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLE_RATE * 2

# Initialize a deque for audio data buffering with a max length of MAX_BUFFER_SIZE.
audio_buffer = deque(maxlen=MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)

# Create a buffer array to hold audio data fetched from the deque (initialization).
fetched_buffer = np.zeros(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, dtype=np.float32)

# Overflow offset to adjust buffer size dynamically, flag to detect issues, and flag to start calculations.
overflow_offset = 0
underflow_bound = -999999
is_calculate_overflow = False

OVERFLOW_OFFSET_DECREMENT = 128
UNDERFLOW_BOUND_ADJUSTMENT = 1.01


def gen_sine_wave(freq, sample_rate=SAMPLE_RATE, frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER):
  """
  Generate a continuous sine wave for the specified frequency.
  :param freq: Frequency of the sine wave to generate
  :param sample_rate: The sample rate for audio playback
  :param frames_per_buffer: Number of frames to generate for each audio buffer
  """
  # Calculate the number of samples required to produce one full cycle of the sine wave.
  samples = int(sample_rate / freq)

  # Create one cycle of the sine wave based on frequency and sample rate.
  wave = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(samples) * freq / sample_rate)

  # Repeat the wave to fill at least one buffer's worth of data.
  while len(wave) < frames_per_buffer:
    # Double the length of wave each time to reach the required frames per buffer.
    wave = np.tile(wave, 2)

  return wave


def audio_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
  """
  Callback function for pyaudio that outputs audio by fetching from audio_buffer.
  :param in_data: Input audio data (not used)
  :param frame_count: Number of frames to fetch from audio_buffer
  :param time_info: Timing information (not used)
  :param status: Audio stream status (not used)
  """
  global audio_buffer, fetched_buffer, overflow_offset, underflow_bound, is_calculate_overflow, UNDERFLOW_BOUND_ADJUSTMENT

  # Check if there are enough frames in the buffer to avoid underflow.
  if len(audio_buffer) < frame_count:
    print('Warning: Buffer underflow')  # Alert on underflow.

    # If audio calculation has started, adjust the underflow_bound to compensate for underflow.
    if is_calculate_overflow and overflow_offset != 0:
      underflow_bound = int(overflow_offset / UNDERFLOW_BOUND_ADJUSTMENT)

    # Reset overflow_offset since we just adjusted for it.
    overflow_offset = 0

    # Return the empty buffer to prevent playback disruption.
    return (fetched_buffer, pyaudio.paContinue)

  # Populate fetched_buffer with data from audio_buffer using popleft to maintain deque order.
  fetched_buffer = np.array(
      list(starmap(audio_buffer.popleft, repeat((), frame_count))), dtype=np.float32)

  # Return the filled buffer to play the audio.
  return (fetched_buffer, pyaudio.paContinue)


# Initialize webcam video capture.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Initialize pyaudio for audio stream.
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Brief delay to allow everything to initialize properly.
time.sleep(1)

# Open an audio stream with specified settings.
audio_stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                      channels=1,
                      rate=SAMPLE_RATE,
                      output=True,
                      frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER // 2,
                      stream_callback=audio_callback)

# Start the audio stream.
audio_stream.start_stream()

# Additional delay to ensure the stream has time to start.
time.sleep(1)

# Begin processing frames and audio while the audio stream is active.
while audio_stream.is_active():
  # Capture a video frame.
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if not ret:  # Exit if frame capture fails.
    break

  # Convert the frame to grayscale for intensity analysis.
  frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # Calculate frequency based on average pixel intensity (scaled to a range of up to 1000 Hz).
  freq = np.mean(frame) / 255 * 1000

  # Check if audio_buffer is less than half full, accounting for the overflow_offset.
  if len(audio_buffer) < (MAX_BUFFER_SIZE // 2) + overflow_offset:
    # Generate a sine wave at the calculated frequency and add it to the buffer.
    next_wave = gen_sine_wave(freq, SAMPLE_RATE)
    audio_buffer.extend(next_wave)
  else:
    # If buffer is too full and overflow_offset reaches or exceeds underflow_bound, adjust for overflow.
    if overflow_offset >= underflow_bound:
      is_calculate_overflow = True  # Enable buffer adjustment calculations.
      # Decrease buffer size by OVERFLOW_OFFSET_DECREMENT to mitigate overflow.
      overflow_offset -= OVERFLOW_OFFSET_DECREMENT

  # Display the calculated frequency on the video frame.
  cv2.putText(frame, f'Frequency: {freq:.2f}', (10, 30),
              cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

  # Display the current overflow_offset on the video frame.
  cv2.putText(frame, f'Overflow offset: {overflow_offset}', (10, 60),
              cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

  # Draw underflow bound
  cv2.putText(frame, f'Underflow bound: {underflow_bound}', (10, 90),
              cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

  # Show the video frame with the frequency and offset annotations.
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

  # Check for the 'q' key to exit the loop and stop the program.
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# Release video capture resources.
cap.release()
# Close all OpenCV windows.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# Stop and close the audio stream.
audio_stream.stop_stream()
audio_stream.close()

# Terminate the pyaudio session.
p.terminate()

The idea is that overflow_offset and underflow_bound are competing with each other to find the optimal value in order to make audio in near-real time.
Lesser value of overflow_offset means near real-time but prone to buffer underflow empty buffer.
A greater value of underflow_bound means the threshold limit of overflow_offset to decrease.
Over time, overflow_offset will try to decrease its value since there are many buffers that make delays.
For every buffer underflow hit, increase underflow_bound 10% greater than the last overflow_offset.
At the end, overflow_offset will be found and stop decrement.
In this algorithm, it's not related to FPS directly.

